# Execute loop controller for every 10 seconds in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, loadrunner

I need to execute few HTTP Requests for a regular interval of every 10 seconds during test. I added them to loop controller. Is there any way to do this in JMeter or LoadRunner?

Comment: You can choose to add a [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) under the Http request set to **10000 miliseconds**.

Comment: In LoadRunner Developer you can use StartInterval and add any code there. https://admhelp.microfocus.com/truweb/en/latest/help/Content/DevWeb/DW-JS-SDK.htm#mt-item-8

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way of implementing this in JMeter is adding a [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) and configure it to send 6 requests per minute

[image]

LoadRunner's equivalent can be done via [Think Time and Pacing](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.60-12.63/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/166950_t_how_to_confugre_rts_manually.htm?Highlight=pacing)